# SPRING AOP within pointcut not processed for set method of a bean

Tags: spring, spring-aop

In short:

a) spring.xml

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean id="circle" class="org.tutorial.spring.model.Circle">
    <property name="name" value="Circle name" />
</bean>

<bean id="triangle" class="org.tutorial.spring.model.Triangle">
    <property name="name" value="Triangle name" />
</bean>

<bean id="shapeService" class="org.tutorial.spring.service.ShapeService" autowire="byName" />

<bean class=" org.tutorial.spring.aspect.LoggingAspect" />
```

b) ShapeService class

```
package org.tutorial.spring.service;

import org.tutorial.spring.model.Circle;

public class ShapeService {

private Triangle triangle;
private Circle circle;

public Triangle getTriangle() {
    return triangle;
}

public void setTriangle(Triangle triangle) {
    this.triangle = triangle;
}

public Circle getCircle() {
    return circle;
}

public void setCircle(Circle circle) {
    this.circle = circle;
}

}
```

c) Circle class

```
package org.tutorial.spring.model;

public class Circle {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    System.out.println("Circle getName");
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    System.out.println("Circle setName");
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

d) LoggingAspect class

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

@Before("allCircleMethods()")
public void securityAdvice() {
    System.out.println("Security Advice is executed!");
}

@Pointcut("within(org.tutorial.spring.model.Circle)")
public void allCircleMethods() {
}

}
```

e) ShapeAOP class (main class to run)

```
public class ShapeAOP {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    ShapeService shapeService = ctx.getBean("shapeService", ShapeService.class);
    System.out.println(shapeService.getCircle().getName());
}

}
```

OUTPUT:

Circle setName
Security Advice is executed!
Circle getName
Circle name

Notice the output that there is no 'Security Advice is executed' before the 'Circle setName' during the Circle bean instantiation.

How come the pointcut within for Circle class didn't get applied to the Circle setName method?

Comment: It would appear that the pointcut is not set up until after the bean has been initialized. Which kind of makes sense. Applying advices to beans that are not fully constructed yet (i.e. in an indeterminate state) opens up all kinds of potential issues. Have you tried explicitly calling your `setName()` method (like in your `main`, for instance) just to verify that the advice is applied then?

Comment: @pap you are right. Does not make sense that the advice gets applied during bean instantiation. I tested it and it confirms your findings. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User pap has answered my question in the comment section